# Как отобразить содержимое объекта

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Есть модульное окно `dijit/Dialog` , в нем должено отображаться содержимое `<div class="wrap-filters-table">`, но вместо этого он просто пишет `[object HTMLDivElement]`. 
Вопрос, как заставить его отображаться корректно?

```
toggle: function() {
        var self = this;
        var myDialog = new Dialog({
            title: 'My Dialog',
            content:'<div class="data-action">' + this.wrapFiltersTableNode + '</div>' + '<br>' +
        '<div class="center margin-top">' +
        '<button data-action="cancel">Cancel</button>' +
        ' ' +
        '<button data-action="ok">OK</button>' +
        '</div>',
            style: 'width: 600px; height: 1000px;'
        });

        myDialog.show();
        this.wrapFiltersTableNode = this.dom.querySelector('.wrap-filters-table');
        this.dom.classList.toggle('short');
        this.updateButtonLabel();
    },
```

Должно отображаться содержимое объекта, следующее примерно : http://jsbin.com/xeyinuroku/edit?html,css,output

Сам div выглядит так:

```
<div class="wrap-filters-table">
  <div class="filter">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит _корректно_? В данном случае это корректное отображение элемента _div_

Comment: вообще интересно как это работает, если значение _wrapFiltersTableNode_ присваивается после того как оно приведено к строке, то есть в строке оно должно было быть скорее пустой строкой. Если конечно оно не заполняется еще где-нибудь

Comment: @Grundy оно заполняется до этого, Коректно это в виде фильтра коем этот объект является, там целая форма с кучей кнопок, не пойму как их впихнуть в модульное окно ибо на странице они занимают много места.

Comment: тогда зачем оно еще раз присваивается ниже?

Comment: @Grundy Да это я туплю я думал не могу понять что надо сделать чтобы оно отобразилось вот и леплю что попало, я только изучаю js поэтому могу писать несусветный бред!

Comment: так что конкретно должно вставиться в шаблон? в принципе два варианта, либо `innerHTML` либо `outerHTML` в зависимости от того _что конкретно нужно вставить_

Comment: @Grundy по задумке должны отобразиться divы в html форме типа <div class="1"><div class="2"></div></div>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44034/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае вставляется непосредственно *объект* html-элемента, в то время как необходимо вставить его содержимое.

Для получения можно воспользоваться [свойством innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
content:'<div class="data-action">' + this.wrapFiltersTableNode.innerHTML + '</div>'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вы просто мой спаситель я уже 2 дня голову ломаю=)